# How to run nohup and write its pid file in a single bash statement

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run my script in background and then write its pid file. I am using nohup to do this.

This is what i came up with,

```
nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & && echo $! > run.pid
```

But this gives a syntax error.

The following doesn't give syntax error but the problem is echo $! doesn't write the correct pid since nohup is run in a sub shell

```
(nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &) && echo $! > run.pid
```

Any solutions for this, given i want a single line statement for achieving this?

Comment: The `&` is a command terminator, much like `;` or `\n`.  That is why `& &&` is a syntax error.

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me the wrong PID.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You already have one ampersand after the redirect which puts your script in background. Therefore you only need to type the desired command after that ampersand, not prefixed by anything else:

```
nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > run.pid
```

Comment: tried this, but getting a pidfile that's 1 process behind for some odd reason. so if the pidfile says 123, the actual process ID is 124. Any ideas?

Comment: @Allen, because nohup forks and a new process is created for the actual command. And sometimes that may not be the exact next pid, e.g. during heavy forking of other processes.

Comment: @Grigor Yosifov, in the command what is the purpose of: 2>&1 ?

Comment: @Zubair it's basically suppressing all of the 1st command console messages by pointing both the error and the standard output to the null device. I've left it as it was there by the original request.

Comment: @GrigorYosifov: Please correct me if I am wrong,  > /dev/null sends the messages to null, Right ? If its the case then how 2>&1 is doing the same thing ?

Comment: @Zubair you're right, but 2>&1 basically takes care of the error output, please check this article https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Comment: `nohup ./run.sh > /dev/null & echo $(($!+1)) > run.pid`

Answer (score 26):

This should work:

```
nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > run.pid
```

Comment: But this uses multiple lines. Can't i do this using single line ?

Comment: Yes, the newline is optional.

Comment: @amit.codename13: Yes of course you can use it like `nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > run.pid` I just placed it in 2 lines for understanding purpose only.

Answer (score 4):

Grigor's answer is correct, but not complete.
Getting the pid directly from the nohup command is not the same as getting the pid of your own process.

running `ps -ef`:

```
root     31885 27974  0 12:36 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo nohup ./myprogram.sh
root     31886 31885 25 12:36 pts/2    00:01:39 /path/to/myprogram.sh
```

To get the pid of your own process, you can use:

```
nohup ./myprogram.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > run.pid
# allow for a moment to pass
cat run.pid | pgrep -P $!
```

Note that if you try to run the second command immediately after nohup, the child process will not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Works with python as well:

```bash
nohup python run_experiment.py > experiment.log & echo $! > experiment.nohup.pid
```