# How to cleanly shutdown a Grails standalone application?

Tags: grails, nohup

What is the best way to stop a Grails application started with:

```
nohup java -jar myapp.war --server-port=9090 &
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254155/how-to-run-nohup-and-write-its-pid-file-in-a-single-bash-statement first write the pid to a file or something then look at scripting it - take a look at tom cat shutdown.sh script - I think a lot of the init scripts just kill the pid

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense... I was hoping that there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand?  How do you want to exit otherwise? You are launching a java process. You can put the above comment in a script and then call /etc/init.d/whatever stop. As I said take a look at tomcat shutdown script  https://github.com/imtiger/Tomcat/blob/master/catalina-home/bin/catalina.sh#L423 you will see it calls catalina.sh as shown this does a kill -0 if it fails it does a kill -9. That's tomcat officially you want to beat that ?

Comment: I was hoping that since it is a Spring Boot app I would be able to enable a shutdown URL or something like that.

Comment: Hmm did some research and it appears that SpringBoot supports the concept of production-ready endpoints. That's what I wanted to do... http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shutdown a Spring Boot Application in a correct way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the process ID:

```
ps -A | grep java
```

If the process id `3114` for example, then stop the process:

```
kill 3114
```

Sometimes, Grails app doesn't kill cleanly, then use:

```
kill -9 3114
```

Optionally, in one of your action in the controller, you can simply write:

```
System.exit()
```

This is the convenient way to shutdown your Grails application which will properly execute all your [Shutdown hooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html) and will cleanly shutdown your app by preventing memory links, releasing resources, closing any streams extra.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716015/2405040

Comment: @esmiralha : so check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38681221/747579)

Comment: `kill 3114` will not work because he use `nohup`.. U need some background on Linux-PS . the only way to kill is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38681221/747579)

Answer (score 0):

```
killall -9 java
```

or

```
 killall -15 java
```

**That's it !** This command sends signals to processes identified by their name.

---

## Why `-9` or `-15` ?

**Because** you use `nohup` which prevents the processes from receiving `SIGHUP`. So, you must use -15 (`SIGTERM`) or -9 (`SIGKILL`) with kill command.